# How To Autostart Youtube Playlist With Low Volume?

Tags: youtube-api

Using this wizard, i cannot get a Youtube Playlist to autoplay With Low Volume.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

have tried iframe, as3, as2.

Need volume/fullscreen controls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because the player parameters (left column) cannot support the control in volume. 
Therefore, embed code is not useful in your case.

In iframe API reference, you can use [`player.setVolume()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setVolume) to set the volume after the player is ready.

If you want to control the volume, you have to write some code in Javascript.

[Example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) (see Loud playback)